# GTK Dialog constructor cannot be used to create instances of a subclass MessageDialog WTF

Tags: dialog, modal-dialog, gtk, pygtk, gtk4

When I run the following code:

```py
 dialog = Gtk.MessageDialog.new(
            None,
            Gtk.DialogFlags.MODAL,
            Gtk.MessageType.QUESTION,
            Gtk.ButtonsType.YES_NO,
            f'Do you really want to {action} "{data["list_element"].name}" ?',
        )
```

I get this error:

```
Dialog constructor cannot be used to create instances of a subclass MessageDialog
```

What does it mean? How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the use of `new`, which seems to be reserved for the parent `Gtk.Dialog` class. From [this source](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dialogs.html#messagedialog), it seems you can use the `Gtk.MessageDialog` constructor directly:

```py
 dialog = Gtk.MessageDialog(
            None,
            Gtk.DialogFlags.MODAL,
            Gtk.MessageType.QUESTION,
            Gtk.ButtonsType.YES_NO,
            f'Do you really want to {action} "{data["list_element"].name}" ?',
        )
```

Comment: thanks, but didn't work :(

Comment: This works for GTK3 but not for GTK4, which the author has tagged.